# How to view active history for the specific day for specific tag

Tags: support, search

Say for example I would like to read entire activities on the tag (emberjs) for the specific date.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js?sort=active&pageSize=50

In the above view, I need to filter based on date, modified, and answered activities alone.

Comment: You can search by tag and last active date ("[ember.js] lastactive:2016-07-26")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be best served if the search option provided by [Modus Tollens](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329611/how-to-view-active-history-for-the-specific-day-for-specific-tag#comment373371_329611) works for you:

> [`[emberjs] lastactive:2016-08-20`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bemberjs%5D+lastactive%3A2016-08-20)

But if you want to know what happend for posts on a particular day more than 7 days ago (due to SEDE only updating once a week) the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/526890?date=2016-01-01&tag=java) might be of use:

```sql
select distinct p.id as [Post Link]
     , case when p.posttypeid = 1 then 'Q' else 'A' end as qa
     , p.creationdate
     , p.score
     , p.owneruserid as [User Link]
from posts  p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join posthistory ph on ph.postid = p.id
where t.tagname = ##tag:string##
and ph.creationdate between ##date:string## and dateadd(d, 1, cast(##date:string## as date))
```